# align paragraph in Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to align my paragraphs on the same horizontal line but I can't find my error do you have a solution?

```
foreach ($articles as $article): ?> 
  <div class="container" id="presentation">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mb-4"></div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="media my-3">
          <span><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>
          <div class="media-body ml-3">
            <h5 class="mt-0"><?= $article['name'] ?></h5>
            <p class="text-justify"><?= $article['content'] ?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

[image]

Comment: plz, mark the question as correct if it answers your question.

Comment: looks like you have a character encoding issue. Make sure your HTML has a utf-8 meta tag, make sure your db, tables, and columns are utf-8, make sure your IDE opens and saves files as UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-12 {width: 100%;}
```

This means that col-12 will take up the whole div block in one line. Try changing it to .col-6

> Working Demo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container" id="presentation">
         <div class="row">
            <?php
               $articles=array(array("name"=>"name1111","content"=>"content1111"),array("name"=>"name222","content"=>"content222222"),array("name"=>"name333333","content"=>"content333333"));
               foreach ($articles as $article): ?> 
                <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="media my-3">
                      <span> <i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>
                      <div class="media-body ml-3">
                         <h5 class="mt-0"><?= $article['name'] ?></h5>
                         <p class="text-justify"><?= $article['content'] ?></p>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
          <?php endforeach ?>
           </div>
         </div>
   </body>
</html>
```